# aws-apigateway RestApi deployOptions failing

Tags: aws-cdk

So I have a problem where I am able to create a REST API with the following declaration

```
const restApi = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'Api_Name_Here', {
      description: 'API Description'
    });
```

I can do a cdk deploy and all is well.  However, when I add the deployOptions to specify a stage name, like this

```
const restApi = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'Api_Name_here', {
      description: 'API Description',
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'dev'
      }
    });
```

It fails, with the following error

```
The final policy size (20806) is bigger than the limit (20480). (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: PolicyLengthExceededException; Request ID: 4d13d438-93ab-441b-bf32-c7a0a442693e)
   Function.addPermission (D:\proj\testing\restApi\cdk\node_modules\@aws-cdk\aws-lambda\lib\function-base.ts:191:5)
   // snipped
```

What can I do to shorten whatever policy is generated or can I break this up somehow?

Comment: If the problem is related to too many endpoints and if by they all are using same lambda, you can use wildcard to shorten rule, check this: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/337

Comment: Yes, that describes my situation exactly.  I have a single Lambda method, with one jar for each endpoint.  I was trying to help avoid cold starts that way.  I'll check the link to see how I can get around that.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm on CDK, not using SAM. How can I fix this?